# Leaking Shower Floor: Shouldn't there be a liner here?

Tags: shower, drain

I'm trying to find out what's wrong with a leaking shower floor in the basement. Having eliminated all the surface possibilities, I removed the drain and hammered out the floor to examine the drain pipe. I dug down to where the pipe is, but I expected to see a liner here. Isn't this where the liner should be, tacked under the pipe mount (don't know what to call that flange)?

[image]

There's definitely a smooth surface here, so I'm at the division between a couple of different layers (i.e., base layer dried and hardened underneath top layer). Everything I've found about drain construction makes it sound like there should be some barrier at this point. I'm worried that the lack of a barrier right here might be the problem (meaning the whole shower's coming out).

Thanks!

Comment: When/where was this built?

Comment: @RonBeyer home remodel, WA, 2017.

Comment: Not on a full concrete slab. Heck, the shower in my 1950s rental property's basement was nothing *but* concrete. Where was the leak manifesting itself?

Comment: @isherwood The leak was manifesting across the bottom of the step and drywall on the outside right at floor level. I took multiple moisture meter readings which seemed to indicate that the leak was coming from floor level (base of wall is always wettest, and moisture appears there and seeps up rather than other way around).